# Move commits from one branch to another with almost the same file contents but completely different commit history

Tags: git

Ok, so I have got a multi-commit task on my branch devel. I have to move those changes to another branch (production), but before about a month ago, we had peculiar system of deployment - after checking everything on devel, person who needed to integrate new changes was making a new commit and integrate it manually. I don't want to do it like that, but I have two branches that weren't merged for about 1,5 years, so I only want to move those commits, and then make a new devel branch.

The tree looks somewhat like that:

```
ft1 -----------c--------------

dev ---a---b-------d-------e---

prod --f---------------g-------
```

and I want it to be

```
ft1 -----------c--------------

dev ---a---b-------d-------e---

prod --f---b-------d---g---e---
```

How can I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inserting the `b` and `d` commits between `f` and `g` is not quite a normal workflow, no matter what VCS one uses.

If you don't mind applying commits `b`, `d` and `e` on the `prod` branch **after** `g` then [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) comes to rescue.

```
git rebase --onto prod a dev
```

As explained in [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase), the command above checks out the `dev` branch, saves the commits in the current branch (`dev`) that are not in the `a` branch (i.e. the commits `b`, `d` and `e`) into a temporary area, checks out the `prod` branch and applies the saved commits, one by one, in their original order.

If it doesn't fail (because of conflicts) your branches will look like this:

```
ft1 -----------c--------------
dev ---a---b-------d-------e---
prod --f---------------g---b---d---e
```

If it fails you have two options:

- resolve the conflicts, commit then run `git rebase --continue`; repeat if needed until all the commits are rebased;
- abort the rebase by running `git rebase --abort`; this will restore the repository in its original state.

#### How to achieve the desired status

However, if you insist on applying the `b` and `d` commits before `g` then you can use [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick).

Create a new branch (let's name it `new`) starting on commit `f` and check it out. Then cherry pick the commits you want, in the order you want (`b`, `d`, `g`, `e`):

```
git checkout -b new f
git cherry-pick b
git cherry-pick d
git cherry-pick g
git cherry-pick e
```

If all the `cherry-pick`s succeed then you're almost done. [Hard reset](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) the branch `prod` to `new` then remove anything you don't need any more (branches `dev` and `new`):

```
git checkout prod
git reset --hard new
git branch -D new dev
```

If any of the cherry picks fail you have the same two options as before:

- either resolve the conflicts, commit and continue (`git cherry-pick --continue`);
- or abort everything: checkout the branch `prod` and remove the branch `new`.

Comment: rebasing like this doesn't work at all, a lot of conflicts, that shouldn't be there, but cherry picking worked, thank you